# Exception Handling with IErrorHandler

Tags: wcf, ierrorhandler

I have a couple of questions regarding IErrorHandler.

1) If I explicitly throw an exception in my service's methods will it get caught by the type implementing the interface?

2) How can I share the type between two different services?

Answer (score 0):

1) yes, when it's marked with attribute for error handling

2) yes, when service configured for that

You can share your error handler among services 
Best place with more information is here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.dispatcher.ierrorhandler.aspx

Also consider that HandleError is method  which multiple threads can execute

Comment: on 1) do you mean that if the service operation is marked with a [FaultContract(typeof(T))] attribute?

Comment: Yes and do not forget to add service behaviour extension for error handling for each service

Comment: What if I want throw a CLR exception, catch it on `ProvideFault()` and construct a `FaultException<typeof(T)>` in order to create the referenced Message of `ProvideFault()`. Do I still need to add the `FaultContractAttribute`?

Comment: Is this a reason for the application pool of IIS on which the WCF service sits on, to close? I've been trying all day to figure this out! I was trying without the `FaultContractAttribute`. I'm gonna try it again with the attribute declared and see what happens.

Comment: If thats the case, how do uncaught exceptions propagate to `ProvideFault()` ? This doesn't make sense. Isn't the purpose of `IErrorHandler` to catch unhandled exceptions on the first place, those thrown from service operations or downstream business components that are not declare with a `FaultContractAttribute`?

Comment: The application pool was getting stopped due to an exception thrown on `HandleError()`. I was doing something wrong while logging.

Apart from that, I think what you claim isn't correct. The `FaultContractAttribute` should be used when you explicitly throw and return `Faults` to the client inside your service operations, something that is tedious and cumbersome. This is the whole point of IErrorHandler, a centralized way to manage exceptions thrown at any level in your operations. I've tested it myself, throwing CLR exceptions from my service ops (not marked with the `FaultContractAttribute`..

Comment: ... and I have successfully constructed Faults on ProvideFault() and returned them to clients.